# How do I force apt to accept dependeny version on install?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install libgphoto2-dev which has the following dependency on:

```
$ sudo apt depends libgphoto2-dev
libgphoto2-dev
  Depends: libexif-dev
  Depends: libgphoto2-6 (= 2.5.27-1build2)
  Depends: pkg-config
    pkg-config:armhf
    pkgconf:armhf
    pkgconf
  Breaks: <libgphoto2-2-dev> (<< 2.5.2-1~)
  Replaces: <libgphoto2-2-dev> (<< 2.5.2-1~)
$
```

However I already have installed a later/higher version of libgphoto2-6

```
$ apt list --installed | grep libgphoto2
libgphoto2-6/now 2.5.29+202205211407~ubuntu22.04.1 arm64 [installed,local]
libgphoto2-l10n/now 2.5.29+202205211407~ubuntu22.04.1 all [installed,local]
libgphoto2-port12/now 2.5.29+202205211407~ubuntu22.04.1 arm64 [installed,local]
$
```

It is a later version so is there a way I can force apt install to accept the later version?

Comment: It is not apt that wants the lower version it is what ever module is using that lower version. No you can not force a lower version to be installed that messes up other modules. Since you did not give the version of Ubuntu there is no way to check what version it uses.

Comment: The `=` in the `Depends:` field means that using ANY other version is a terrible idea: It will probably fail (probably, not maybe). You can force it, it's your system. When it fails, our only advice will be to revert to the original version.

Comment: Also, bolting newer software onto an LTS release (like your 22.04) is also generally a Bad Idea, unless you know how to maintain the system properly. This site is soaked in the tears of folks who did that, failed to maintain it, and then --eventually-- their system broke completely, unable to resolve the conflicting requirements of the wrong-version and non-Ubuntu packages. The exception, of course, is using Snap packages, which are designed to keep up-to-date without harming the underlying LTS OS.